# Adjusting death rate based on known half-life

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, biology, mathematical-biology

Most health applications use exponential decay for estimating the death rate. This assumes at every age, there is an equal chance of dying. Is there a **simple** way to slightly improve this assumption by centering the death rate based on a known half-life (defined as the time when half of the population is gone)?

For example, if the expected age is known, then the younger agent (age < expected age) has a lower chance of dying, and the older agent (age > expected age) has an increased chance of dying. However, this new distribution should be so that the expected mean does not change.

I could use an age structure model or build a linear age-adjusted death distribution, but I'm sure something like this is out there. I just don't know exactly the terms to search for.